# Is there any advantage in buying tickets in advance for the train in Moroccos?

Tags: trains, price, morocco

I will have to travel between Fes and Casablanca.
However, I am unsure about the travel hour (not day).

I see that it's possible to buy the tickets in advance, on the website.
This would usually be my preference, to avoid last minute rush.
However, given that I don't know exactly at what time I need to travel I was wondering if it's worth buying in advance.

My questions can be narrowed down to:

- Are there any discounts if I buy in advance on the website?
- Is there the risk that tickets are sold out on the day I want to travel? (Buying in advance eliminates the risk)
- any other advantage I might be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reflects only my experience. I hope it helps:

- Are there any discounts if I buy in advance on the website?

Yes, if you buy in advance. Not sure how long in advance though. I bought the tickets with the standard fare. However, I did some simulations, and I was able to find cheaper tickets if booking well in advance.

- Is there the risk that tickets are sold out on the day I want to travel? (Buying in advance eliminates the risk)

Not sure, but the train I used was quite full all the way (2nd class). All seats were full in my wagon. I would say it's advisable to buy in advance. Of course, this might depend on day / hour. I travelled from Fes to Casablanca, Friday at ~11h

- any other advantage I might be missing?

It's easy to buy online. Probably easier than in the station if you don't know the local practices and language.